# Does express provide a mechanism similar to hapi's server.bind()?

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js

I am working in an environment where only express is available.  With hapi I frequently use the server.bind() function to ensure that a resource is available in all my routes.  However, I am unable to find analogous functionality for express.

How are resources referenced across routes in express?

Example hapi code:

```
var gui_db = new Sqlite3.Database('./gui_test.sqlite');
var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({ port: 6000 });
server.bind({gui_db: gui_db});
```

In another context I can refer to `gui_db` via `this.gui_d`b.

Comment: Never used hapi. But maybe this can be helpful: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals

Comment: Very interesting.  I'll give that a go.

Comment: @tomtom, Thank you for the tip.  That seems to be the express way of doing what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @tomtom for answering the question (albeit as a comment).   The answer is to use app.locals.  As long as the app is contextually in view you will have access to the resource bound to it.

```
app.locals.strftime = require('strftime');
```

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals